# Creating an arraylist of names with lowest scores

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have an a tournament class which I try to obtain winners by obtaining the lowest scores and making an arraylist from it. I thought maybe I could use my winnerScore method into my winners method?

This is my attempt:
(but i end up with an error because they aren't the same type)

```
/**
 * Returns the list of winners, that is, the names of those players
 * with the lowest total score.
 * The winners' names should be stored in the same order as they occur
 * in the tournament list.
 * If there are no players, return empty list.
 * @return list of winners' names
 */
public ArrayList<String> winners() {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    result.add(players);

    // Supply this code!
    return result;
}
```

I have this method that I have made, is there some way to incoperate it into winners method?

```
/*
 * Assume as precondition that the list of players is not empty.
 * Returns the winning score, that is, the lowest total score.
 * @return winning score
 */
public int winningScore() {
    Player thePlayer = players.get(0);
    int result = thePlayer.totalScore();
    // Supply this code!
    for(int i=0; i <par.length; i++)
        if(par[i] > result)
            result = par[i];

    return result;
}
```

This is the Junit test for the winners method:

```
@Test(timeout=3000)
public void testWinners() {
    int [] par = {3,4,5,4,5,3,4,3,5,3,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,3};
    int [] scores1 = {3,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4};
    int [] scores2 = {4,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4};
    int [] scores3 = {3,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,5};
    Tournament T = new Tournament(par);
    T.enter("Norman",  2, scores1);
    T.enter("Palmer",  4, scores2);
    T.enter("Scott",  1, scores3);
    ArrayList<String> winners = T.winners();
    assertTrue(winners.get(0).equals("Norman"));
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You start by creating an empty list, then you test if this empty list is empty, and if o, return null. So you always return null. And you shouldn't, ever. Rea the javadoc f the method.

Comment: Are you sure your winnng score does what you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't leave this one alone. Improvements:

```
@Test(timeout=3000)
public void testWinners() {
    Tournament t = new Tournament();
    // int [] par = {3,4,5,4,5,3,4,3,5,3,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,3}; // par does not matter
    int [] scores1 = {3,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4};
    int [] scores2 = {4,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4};
    int [] scores3 = {3,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,5};
    t.enter("Norman", 2, scores1);
    t.enter("Palmer", 4, scores2);
    t.enter("Scott", 1, scores3);
    assertTrue(winners.get(0).equals("Palmer"));
}
```

And the class:

```
public class Tournament {

  List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

  private void enter(String name, int par, int[] scores) {
    players.add(new Player(name, par, scores));
  }

  public List<Player> getWinners() {
    List<Player> ps = new ArrayList<Player>(players);
    Collections.sort(ps);
    return ps;
  }

  private class Player implements Comparable<Player> {

    public String name;
    public int totalScore;

    public Player(String name, int par, int[] scores) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int score : scores) {
            totalScore += score;
        }
        //System.out.println("   " + name + " " + totalScore + ", par " + par + ", total " + (totalScore - par));
        totalScore -= par;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Player o) {
        return Integer.compare(totalScore, o.totalScore);
    }

  }

}
```